# split array values into two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I currently am trying to figure out how to split the values inside my array. I have looked for some code to put me on the right path, but have had no luck. Ideally what I would like to do is take the following input and split it to two separate arrays. each pair listed below ie: (12,13) is one array value.

12,13
12,14
12,15
12,16
12,17
12,18
12,21
12,22

any assistance you can give is muchly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the expected output? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Yes give us more details , and also is your values inside a text file or what

Comment: The first array would contain 8 values, all listed as 12 as per the left hand column, and them the other array would also have eight values with the right hand side populating those.

@FaceOfJock yes these values that you see in the example are from a text file.

Comment: What have you tried? (Hint: [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) might help you)

Comment: I have used explode, however it seems to still put those values into an array as array ( [0] => 12, 13 ) which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're having one array with those values above, eg:

```
$foo = array("12,13", "12,14", "12,15", ...);
$outA = array();
$outB = array();
foreach($foo as $value)
{
    list($x, $y) = explode(",",$value);
    $outA[] = $x;
    $outB[] = $y;
}
print_r($outA);
print_r($outB);
```

You'd probably want some error checking in there somewhere though.

If you don't (yet) have the numbers in an array but in a text file just use PHPs [file](http://www.php.net/file) function to get them there.